# Making a tcp/ip connection from Raspberry PI to Windows server

Tags: python, tcp, raspberry-pi

I wrote a socket server program on a Windows PC and the client side for the raspberry pi - both in Python.

When I run both locally using localhost - it works fine.

When I move the client program to the PI (both connected to the same local subnet via WIFI), I can't connect.

If the Windows Firewall is on - no connection and no error message. I created rules to enable the appropriate port number (50000)

If the Windows Firewall is off - then I get connection refused.

Just to isolate my client program - I did a curl from the PI and same results depending on the setting for the firewall.

I can ping from the PI to the PC regardless of Firewall setting.

If I open a browser on the PC and do a localhost:50000 - that connects. When I do with the host pc IP address:50000 - doesn't work.

Comment: Have a read here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/72882529/2836621